# I submitted a paper to a journal one week ago. What does "Awaiting ME Processing" mean?

Tags: publications

The status from the very 1st day is "Awaiting ME Processing". Can someone tell me what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The acronym ME most likely stands for "Managing Editor" or "Manuscript Editor", and so the message says that the paper is awaiting processing by this person.  As shown in [this question on the process for journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like), that initial "processing" step usually involves an initial assessment by that initial editor, and if it passes that hurdle it will then be sent out for peer review by referees.